# Is it possible to run a java compiled programe through javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

I am developing a local app through a website with javascript. The input for this app is the output of a java command-line program that the user already executed. Is there any way of executing the compiled program through javascript, so that the user only needs to see the web interface?

In other words, is there anyway of executing a command-line java programm via javascript?

Comment: Do you mean via NodeJS?

Comment: I don't think so as JavaScript cannot interact with the files present on the system unless you do some kind of hack on it.

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript. You might be able to run a JVM within NodeJS and run your Java Application through it, but please don't

Comment: You using `nodejs` ?

Comment: Using Node.js, you can fork a **[child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)** that can call pretty much anything you can call on the command-line, including a Java program.  If the Java program is interactive, though, it would get ugly.

Comment: Run the Java app on your server with Jetty/Tomcat etc. Provide a RESTful API. Have the JavaScript make a web request and interpret the result.

Comment: No, I'm not using Node.js or a server. Everything runs basically only on the browser. The program is not interactive: once you give the command, it returns the expected files. Thank you all for the suggestions, I am going to start trying implementing some of them.